# Create registry keys to remote systems but with issue

Tags: powershell

To me if I am able to start a service on a remote machine when referencing them from a text file I should be able to manipulate registry keys. But I am not sure why I'm not able to do so. What am I doing wrong here? The StartWinRM works on remote systems and it enables it without any issues. When I ran this it creates the keys local to my machine. Why is this?

```
$Computers = Get-Content -Path 'D:\HomeFolder\MachineNames.txt'

foreach ($computer in $Computers) {
    If (test-connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        Try {
                Set-Service -ComputerName $computer -Name WinRM -StartupType Automatic -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
                StartWinRM -Computer $computer
                
                Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {
                New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\" -Name Name1 -PropertyType String -Value 0 -Force
                New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\" -Name Name2 -PropertyType String -Value "Description" -Force
                New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\" -Name Name3 -PropertyType String -Value 1 -Force
                } -Credential $cred
                

            $status = "Success"
            }
        Catch {
            $status = "Failed"
              }
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
Connecting to remote server ComputerName failed with the following error message : The WinRM client cannot process the request. If the 
authentication scheme is different from Kerberos, or if the client computer is not joined to a domain, then HTTPS transport must be used or the destination machine 
must be added to the TrustedHosts configuration setting. Use winrm.cmd to configure TrustedHosts. Note that computers in the TrustedHosts list might not be 
authenticated.
```

Comment: Wrap the `New-ItemProperty` lines inside the scriptblock of [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) and add parameter `-ComputerName $computer`. Also add the `-Credential` parameter with a valid, admin credentials object

Comment: Let me try that and I'll report back. Thanks.

Comment: I even manually enabled WinRM service on the remote machine and I still get this error. Not sure what else it could be. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Are you on a domain environment? You have to set your network to private if you're on a personal network. Does DCOM remoting work? Try any `Get-WmiObject` call against it.

Comment: I commented out everything inside the `try{  }` and this `Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object -Property *` worked against the machine that was on the text file.

Comment: Could you try [this function](https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/4918-enable-psremoting) and use the `-Protocol DCOM` argument against that machine and see what it does for you? You may have to uncomment the credentials to use it with admin creds if you're not using kerberos.

Comment: I didn't try this because I don't know exactly what the script is actually doing in the background. There must be other way to make this easier and make it work.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone interested, I fixed my problem:

```
         $computers = Get-Content "D:\HomeFolder\MachineNames.txt"
         foreach ($computer in $computers){
         if (Test-Path -Path "\\$computer\d$\<some_older_existing_folder>"){   
            
            $reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('LocalMachine', $computer )
            $regKey= $reg.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node",$true) 
            $regKey.SetValue("Key1","0",[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::String)
            $regKey.SetValue("Key2","1",[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::String)
            $regKey.SetValue("Key3","1",[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::String)



            }
            Write-Host "Keys already exist" -ForegroundColor Yellow
            }
```